# Local variable referenced before Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
def popLast(aLinkedList):
    ptr = aLinkedList
    while ptr != None:
        if ptr['next']['next'] == None and ptr['next'] != None:
            del_node = ptr['data']
            ptr['next'] = ptr['next']['next']
        ptr = ptr['next']

    return (del_node,ptr)
```

When I put

```
myLinkedList = createList(['a', 'b', 0, [1, 2]])
for i in range(getLength(myLinkedList)):
    (a, myLinkedList) = popLast(myLinkedList)
print(a, end = ", new list: ")
printList(myLinkedList)
```

It keeps giving me

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'del_node' referenced before assignment

When I just use `popLast(myLinkedList)`, there is no problem. Everything works fine. I don't know whether it is because my returning tuple is the problem.

Comment: The reference to `createlist` is not explained in your code. Please give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note: PEP8 suggests that you should use `while ptr is not None` instead of `while ptr != None`.

Answer (score 1):

If an empty list is passed in, then del_node is never initialized. This is what is causing the error. To change this, first initialize del_node to None:

```
def popLast(aLinkedList):
    ptr = aLinkedList
    del_node = None
    while ptr is not None:
    ...
```